# Index reference retrieving wrong values

Tags: r, indexing

I have generated a data frame in R consisting of one column of dates by querying SQL. That part of the code works fine, but when I try to select index items 1 and 6 of the array I am getting the wrong results. For example, if the data frame produces the following results:

```
1   2014-11-17;
2   2014-11-14;
3   2014-11-13;
4   2014-11-12;
5   2014-11-11;
6   2014-11-10;
7   2014-11-07;
8   2014-11-06;
9   2014-11-05;
10  2014-11-04;
11  2014-11-03
```

I want elements 1 and 6, but when I try, it returns 2014-11-16 for element 1 (TestDate) as opposed to 2014-11-17 and for element 6 (ValDate) I get 2014-11-09 instead of 2014-11-10. This is how I have coded it so far:

#### Parameters

```
Today <- Sys.Date()

LookBack <- as.Date(Sys.Date()-14, format = "%y-%m-%d")
```

#### Source data

```
Sql1 <- paste("SELECT DISTINCT Date",
              " FROM dbo.Example_Database",
              " WHERE Date BETWEEN  '",LookBack,"' AND '",Today,"'",
              " ORDER BY Date desc",sep="")
DateArray = data.frame(sqlQuery(dbConnection1,Sql1))
```

#### Reference dates

```
TestDate <- as.Date(DateArray[1,1])

ValDate <- as.Date(DateArray[6,1])
```

Comment: Without a database it is not possible to say what's wrong since the code is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the dates were in EST time, and R was converting them to GMT, and therefore will the indexing was extracting the correct date, the conversion meant that its value was for 1 day earlier EST time. 
You can check the timezone by using the function as.POSIXct, i.e

```
> as.POSIXct(DateArray[1,1])
[1] "2014-11-18 EST"
```

To avoid conversion to GMT time I used

```
> TestDate <- as.Date(DateArray[1,1], tz = "")
```

This returns the date I was looking for, i.e the date as it appears in the data frame and not converted to GMT time.